# how to append pages from file2.pdf to file1.pdf

Tags: c#, append, itext

how to append all the pages in file1.pdf from file2.pdf using (C#) itextsharp
insert page method.please provide the sample code.
i found this code on itext pdf please provide the sample code to work for c#

```
    ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(null);
while (rs.next()) {
ct.addElement(new Paragraph(24,
new Chunk(rs.getString("country"))));
}
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
PdfReader stationery = new PdfReader(Stationery.STATIONERY);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
PdfImportedPage page = stamper.getImportedPage(stationery, 1);
int i = 0;
while(true) {
stamper.insertPage(++i, reader.getPageSize(1));
stamper.getUnderContent(i).addTemplate(page, 0, 0);
ct.setCanvas(stamper.getOverContent(i));
ct.setSimpleColumn(36, 36, 559, 770);
if (!ColumnText.hasMoreText(ct.go()))
break;
}
stamper.close();
```

Comment: Don't be lazy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365986/documentation-for-itextsharp

Comment: i have already mentioned using itext sharp i tried the samples i want to achieve the above mentioned condition dont simply navigate to other link simply by giving the url if the soultion is not mentioned there.

Comment: My comment was made prior to your edit, not that it made any difference to the validity of my point - if I were to search around enough for the solution if it were my problem I'd find it. I don't think many people on SO appreciate the extra noise of questions that could quite easily be solved within minutes by searching for the solution yourself.

Comment: I am not able to find the solution that's why i have posted the problem.

Comment: Are you being serious?? http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=itextsharp+merge+two+pdf+c%23 Stop being lazy.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but in the provided links no where the stamper.insertpage method is used to add the pages in file1.pdf from  file2.pdf.

Comment: stop being lazy from just coping the links with out understanding the problem.

Comment: A better understanding of the problem can only come from a better explanation by yourself. Even overlooking your slightly broken English the style in which you've asked the question is poor. If you were to click around and look enough on the google results page I've just linked you to you *will* find your answer - which is why I'm saying you're lazy.

Comment: Even more proof you're unbelievably lazy - http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=itextsharp+insertpage (most are even from SO) - just have a quick search, for your sake, learn to help yourself, you can't be spoon fed answers if you want to succeed as a developer.

Comment: if you do not have answers keep quite don't make comments unnecessary.

Comment: This is not the first time i am posting any question on SO, this question is for those who have already worked on itextsharp.

Comment: I do have answers, and I've posted them. Your solution is stop being lazy and expecting the solution without showing an effort from yourself first. This is now just noise, so I won't be commenting again.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Simple .NET PDF Merger](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28283/Simple-NET-PDF-Merger) article.

> The presented PDF merger uses the open source PDF library iTextSharp
>   to process PDF files.